# Getting "Couldn't connect to realm service" error while joining rhel7 instance to a domain

Tags: chef, timeout, rhel7, dbus

I am trying to join a `rhel7` node to a domain using a chef cookbook but getting error:

```
realm: Couldn't connect to realm service: Error calling
StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.realmd:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of
org.freedesktop.realmd timed out
```

Even if I install only `realm` package and try to run `realm` command it times out (specific to `rhel7`).

Answer (score 1):

Is realmd running? You can verify this by running:

```
systemctl status realmd.service
```

The if it's not running you can start it with:

```
systemctl start realmd
```

And then make sure it starts at boot:

```
systemctl enable realmd
```

Answer (score 1):

**Resolution**
1. Restart the RealmD service:
FOR RHEL7/Centos7

```
# systemctl restart realmd.service 
# systemctl enable realmd.service
```

FOR RHEL6/CentOS6

```
#service realmd.service restart
#chkconfig realmd on
```

2. If above restarting did not worked we need to restart the server, rebooting server worked for me.

**Root Cause**

- The system was not rebooted or necessary services are not restarted after upgrade.
- As with any application it can not pick up new changes until it is restarted. However, since dbus is so low in the stack and it is so crucial to the system we recommend a reboot of your server in order to maintain system stability after a dbus change.
- This is an expected behavior for an application to need a restart on a change, but with something like dbus, systemd, kernel, glibc, etc, we recommend a system reboot.